# How to configure sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths for JaCoCo/SonarQube?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

SonarQube 7.7 shows the following warning for a Java project analysis:

> Property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath' is deprecated (JaCoCo binary format). 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' should be used instead (JaCoCo XML format).

The Gradle based project is configured via `sonar-project.properties` as follows:

```properties
sonar.projectKey=MyExampleLib
sonar.projectName=MyExample Library
sonar.sources=src/main/java
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/test.exec
sonar.junit.reportsPath=build/test-results/test
sonar.java.test.binaries=build/classes/test
sonar.java.binaries=build/classes/java/main
sonar.binaries=build/classes
sonar.projectVersion=$libVersion
```

The SonarQube server URL is injected via (otherwise you end up with a "localhost:9000" error):

[image: Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment]

The SonarQube analysis is triggered via Jenkins and the [JaCoCo plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jacoco) v.3.0.4 with the following Job configuration:

[image: JaCoCo configuration]

I read that a `report.xml` is picked up by `xmlReportPaths`. How can I generate it?

## Related

- https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/919
- https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/commit/6babdb5233217b0812a85f6b1673aabe7f0fd47e

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that your build is based on Gradle. It would be easier to use jacoco and [sonarqube](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube) plugins in the gradle build

```groovy
plugins {
    id "jacoco"
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.8"
}
```

you don't need `sonar-project.properties`, analysis is configured from your build. You can customize default values in sonarqube configuration

```groovy
// in build.gradle
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/*Generated.java"
    }
}
```

To enable coverage you need to configure gradle to generate XML report

```groovy
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}
```

And then run with `gradle build jacocoTestReport sonarqube`. More details can be found [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151) and in [SonarScanner for Gradle doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/)

Comment: The build is based on Gradle. I successfully generated the report file in `build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml` - I hope the file name fits for the SonarQube plugin - I read about `report.xml` before. - Please add in your answer whether I can leave out the `sonar-project.properties` configuration. How does SonarQube pick up variables and paths which I defined such as `projectKey`, ...?

Comment: I checked the "Analysis property defaults". Some Gradle defaults match my current configuration in `sonar-project.properties` but not all. So I cannot get rid of it. How can I customize the value of individual sonar properties without using a `sonar-project.properties`?  - BTW: Please fix this typo `classeDir` in the docs.

Comment: I added the paragraph about customizing the default values. Thanks for noting the typo

Comment: Thank you. I managed to migrate to the `sonarqube` plugin configuration block as well as the `xmlReportPaths`. The warnings disappeared in the SonarQube web interface. - I specified `build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml` manually, just to be sure the path fits ^^. I like to mention that in `sonar.java.test.binaries=build/classes/test` **the value changed** to `property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "build/classes/java/test"` once I used the sonarqube configuration block - mind the `java`.

Comment: @TiborBlenessy I am getting the below message in Jenkins Console, I have sonar-project. properties file, but when I did run it in localhost path is correct

No coverage report can be found with sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='app/build/reports/jacocoTestReport/jacocoTestReport.xml'. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml

Comment: @Girish comment system on SO is not good enough to troubleshoot such issues, I would invite you to describe your problem on https://community.sonarsource.com/

Comment: @TiborBlenessy Posted in Community...but I am not getting any help

Comment: @Girish can you share the link?

Answer (score 19):

We can generate Jacoco reports in XML format by specifying `xml.enabled` value to `true` and providing `destination path` in the reports section.

```
plugins {
      id "org.sonarqube" version "2.8"
}
```

```
    jacocoTestReport {
        group = "Reporting"
        reports {
            xml.enabled true
            csv.enabled false
            //to create coverage report in html
            html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/coverage")
            //for XML
            xml.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco.xml")
        }
    }
```

The SonarQube properties can be also configured through the `build.gradle` file. As `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` and `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` are deprecated properties from the sonar version of 7.7 which should be replaced with `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths`.

- Configuring the Sonarqube properties through the `build.gradle`

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.projectName', 'MyExample Library'
        property 'sonar.projectKey', 'MyExampleLib'
        property 'sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin', 'jacoco'
        property 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths', "${project.buildDir}/reports/jacoco.xml"
    }
}
```

- If you wish to do that through `sonar-project.properties` then update the deprecated properties mentioned below to the suggested one.

```
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/reports/jacoco.xml
```

Finally, by executing `gradle jacocoTestReport sonarqube` command, the jacoco test report files such as `${project.buildDir}/reports/jacoco.xml` and `${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec` will be generated for SonarQube.

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'html' for task ':jacocoTestReport' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.

Comment: Have you tried  `html.required = true` in report closure? Which version of Gradle you are using?

Answer (score 3):

In Maven (pom.xml), simple add (under properties):

```
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
        ../app-project-name/target/jacoco-report/jacoco.xml
    </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
</properties>
```